# Python Requests to Java OkHttp for Android

Tags: android, python-requests, okhttp

I have the following code working perfectly in Python:

```
login_data = {'identifier': 'something@email.com', 'password': 'Password'}

url = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/login?fields="
p = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(login_data))

if p.status_code is 200:
    print("SUCCESS")
else:
    print("ERROR")
```

I want to convert it to Java using OkHttp to be able to implement it in Android Studio.
I have written the following code but it gives `Status Code: 422` which according to Google means Unprocessable Entity:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String url = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/login?fields=";
String login_data = "{\"identifier\": \"something@email.com\", \"password\": \"Password\"";
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(login_data, MediaType.parse("application/json"));

    Request postRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();

    client.newCall(postRequest).enqueue(new Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e)
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "ERROR - " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException
        {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                Log.i("LOG", "SUCCESS - " + response.body().string());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("LOG", "FAILED. Status Code: " + String.valueOf(response.code));
            }
        }
    });
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing closing bracket in the request body at java implementation.

`"{\"identifier\": \"something@email.com\", \"password\": \"Password\"}"`

Comment: NOICE! Did you laugh? Be honest xd
Well as this is solved, I want to ask one more thing: I have now logged in into my account and now I want to open the following url: https://www.duolingo.com/vocabulary/overview. In Python I can make a Post and Get Request in the same session. What can I do here?

Comment: Link responds 404 but you should probably use a `get` request with session informations (cookie, token ...)

Comment: The Error is because you have to login to Duolingo first. And I will look into that. Thanks! Any good references?